# Stuck with the Google API YouTube Search example in ASP.NET MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous, youtube-api, async-await

Been stuck for days, hoping someone can help me.

I have been trying to run the YouTube 'Search by keyword' example from [Google's API examples for .net](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet) in a VS 2013 Express for Web MVC4 project, and the `ExecuteAsync()` calling the Google API never comes back.

I believe the example code works as I tested it in VS 2013 Express for Windows Desktop as a console application and it came back fine. Also the stats in google's developers console tell me the API request is being received.

Here is what I did:

I created a new VS 2013 Express for Web MVC4 project called GoogleTest and installed the 'Install-Package Google.Apis.YouTube.v3' package.

I then added the following model.

```
public class SearchYouTube
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public async Task RunYouTube()
    {
        var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            ApiKey = " <MY DEVELOPER KEY HERE> ",
            ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
        });

        var searchListRequest = youtubeService.Search.List("snippet");
        searchListRequest.Q = "googleapi examples"; // Replace with your search term.
        searchListRequest.MaxResults = 50;

        // Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified query term.
        var searchListResponse = await searchListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

        List<string> videos = new List<string>();
        List<string> channels = new List<string>();
        List<string> playlists = new List<string>();

        // Add each result to the appropriate list, and then display the lists of
        // matching videos, channels, and playlists.
        foreach (var searchResult in searchListResponse.Items)
        {
            switch (searchResult.Id.Kind)
            {
                case "youtube#video":
                    videos.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.VideoId));
                    break;

                case "youtube#channel":
                    channels.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.ChannelId));
                    break;

                case "youtube#playlist":
                    playlists.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.PlaylistId));
                    break;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Videos:\n{0}\n", string.Join("\n", videos)));
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Channels:\n{0}\n", string.Join("\n", channels)));
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Playlists:\n{0}\n", string.Join("\n", playlists)));
    }
}
```

Then I call the above class in the Home controller like so:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "MVC example";

    SearchYouTube searchObject = new SearchYouTube();
    searchObject.RunYouTube().Wait();

    return View();
}
```

Running this in the debugger, the program steps into but never returns from this line in the `SearchYouTube` class above:

```
var searchListResponse = await searchListRequest.ExecuteAsync();
```

Can anyone help explain what I am doing wrong or what I am missing??

Comment: what if you do `await searchListRequest.ExecuteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)`?

Comment: Thanks i3arnon, adding ' .ConfigureAwait(false) ' to the call worked!  Awesome!

Any thoughts as to why it's needed in the web application code but not in program console code??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have a deadlock on your hands because you're doing [*"sync over async"*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx). When you use `Task.Wait` you're blocking and wasting a thread. After the inner `async` operation (i.e. `await searchListRequest.ExecuteAsync();`) completes it evidently needs that same thread to continue processing the rest of the method.

All that happens because of the `SynchronizationContext` present in ASP.Net which is captured when `await` is used so that the continuation would be posted to it. When you use `ConfigureAwait(false)` you're configuring the continuation to not run on the captured context and use the `ThreadPool` instead.

In console apps there is no SC and so every continuation runs on the `ThreadPool`. It's as if every `await` had `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

To solve this deadlock you can use `ConfigureAwait(false)` or even better, make the MVC method `async` so you don't need to block synchronously ([more on `async` in MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4)):

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "MVC example";

    SearchYouTube searchObject = new SearchYouTube();
    await searchObject.RunYouTube();

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Thank you i3arnon, I have made the MVC method async and all is well!
Appreciate the help!!